# How to kill an windows application from R using a port number?

Tags: r, cmd

My be it is a silly question. How can I pass the following windows command (To kill process running on 1234 port) from R:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":1234" ^| find "LISTENING"')
    do taskkill /f /pid %a
```

So far I have tried...

```
# Create the string
kill <- "for /f \"tokens=5\" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find \":1234\" ^| find \"LISTENING\"') do taskkill /f /pid %a"

# Check
cat(shQuote(kill, type="cmd"))
# "for /f \"tokens=5\" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find \":1234\" ^| find \"LISTENING\"') do taskkill /f /pid %a"

# Run the cmd
system(shQuote(kill, type="cmd"), wait = F)

# Warning message:
#   In system(shQuote(kill, type = "cmd"), wait = F) :
#   '"for /f \"tokens=5\" 0x0p+0 in ('netstat -aon ^| find \":1234\" ^| find \"LISTENING\"') do taskkill /f /pid 0x0p+0"' not found
```

**Edit: Something my help**

I got a combination of quotes which gives(cat) same string as the win command.

```
kill <- 'for /f "tokens=5" %a in (\'netstat -aon ^| find ":1234" ^| find "LISTENING"\') do taskkill /f /pid %a'
cat(kill)
# From Cat:    for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":1234" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a
# Win Command: for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":1234" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a
```

**Extra:**

The following code will run a shiny app on port 1234. Tried to kill this app from another R session.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE, port = 1234))
```

Comment: Not that it probably matters, but you are using `type="cmd"` in the check, but not the actual call, when you use `shQuote`.  Maybe you can try to get simpler system calls to work, and then build up from there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes.. I have missed that. Both will give same result that can be checked by       identical(shQuote(kill, type="cmd"), shQuote(kill)). Though I will edit.

Comment: My guess would be that you need to use `shell()` since `for` is not an executable but a shell command. I would start with a much simpler call, confirm that works, and then build the more complicated chain of commends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @HenrikB for your suggestion. Yes... the following code with shell() function is working ...

```
# Create the string
kill <- 'for /f "tokens=5" %a in (\'netstat -aon ^| find ":1234" ^| find "LISTENING"\') do taskkill /f /pid %a'

# Check
cat(kill)
# From Cat:    for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":1234" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a
# Win Command: for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":1234" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a

# Run the cmd
shell(kill)
# E:\Raja\Installed_Software\R-3.5.1>taskkill /f /pid 18772 
# SUCCESS: The process with PID 18772 has been terminated.
```